# 3D / FPS Camera Issues - SDL2

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, game-engine, sdl-2

I got a problem with my code, I'm trying to make a First Person 3D Camera.
I use SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL) to get the pressed keys.

When I press one of the defined keys nothing happens, why?

Camera (Controll):

```
void Control(float movevel, float mousevel, bool mi, SDL_Window* window)
{
if (mi)  //if the mouse is in the screen
{
    int MidX = 640 / 2;   //middle of the screen
    int MidY = 480 / 2;
    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);    //we don't show the cursor
    int tmpx, tmpy;
    SDL_GetMouseState(&tmpx, &tmpy); //get the current position of the cursor
    camYaw += mousevel*(MidX - tmpx);   //get the rotation, for example, if the mouse current position is 315, than 5*0.2, this is for Y
    camPitch += mousevel*(MidY - tmpy); //this is for X
    lockCamera();
    //SDL_WarpMouse(MidX, MidY);       //move back the cursor to the center of the screen
    SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(window, MidX, MidY);

    const Uint8* kstate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    if (kstate[SDLK_w])
    {
        if (camPitch != 90 && camPitch != -90)
        {       //if we are facing directly up or down, we don't go forward, it will be commented out, when there will be gravity
            moveCamera(movevel, 0.0);        //move forward
        }

        moveCameraUp(movevel, 0.0);      //move up/down
    }

    if (kstate[SDLK_s])
    {
        //same, just we use 180 degrees, so we move at the different direction (move back)
        if (camPitch != 90 && camPitch != -90)
        {
            moveCamera(movevel, 180.0);
        }

        moveCameraUp(movevel, 180.0);
    }

    if (kstate[SDLK_a])
    {       //move left
        moveCamera(movevel, 90.0);
    }

    if (kstate[SDLK_d])
    {  //move right
        moveCamera(movevel, 270);
    }
}

glRotatef(-camPitch, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(-camYaw, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
```

Main (Loop)

```
while (running)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    SDL_Event ev;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
    {
        switch (ev.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                int x, y;

                SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
                Main::handleKeys(ev.key.keysym.scancode, x, y);
                break;
        }
    }

    Main::update(window);
    Main::render(window);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
```

Main (Update):

```
void Main::update(SDL_Window* window)
{
Control(0.2, 0.2, mousein, window);
UpdateCamera(0.2); //move the camera to the new location
}
```

Comment: Calling `glRotatef` in your keayboard handler is a very bad idea in most cases. The matrices are likely to be overwritten in your render function.

Comment: I changed that, Still no success :/

Comment: What type of matric are youusing?

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SDL_PumpEvents() to update the state array. (From the SDL_GetKeyboardState() wiki).
I believe that if you do:

```
SDL_PumpEvents();
SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
```

you should get the results you are looking for. (You need to SDL_PumpEvents every loop as well as SDL_GetKeyboardState obviously)

(EDIT)
Another option:

```
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym){
            case SDLK_w
                (... code)
                break;
            case SDLK_s:
                (... code)
                break;
            case SDLK_a:
                (... code)
                break;
            case SDLK_d:
                (... code)
                break;
```

You can also send the event.key.keysym.sym to a function and use it their ofcourse.

Comment: Thank you, but, for some reason it didn't do anything, It didn't change :/

Idk why, but may there be an other way to get Keyboard input? (Without GLUT)

Comment: This should work! Can you show me the handleKeys() code? I left you another way to do it if it helps.

Comment: Update keys is empty for now, but I tried the way you gave me, it works.. but.

In that way you can't press multiple keys at the same time. :/

Comment: You can press multiple keys at the same time cause you have it, as you should, on a loop with ' while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev))'. If you put the code you have above inside the if's, inside the case's of the code i showed you it should work.

Comment: :) A like would be apreciated :) I need to be able to comment :P Need to have 50 rep for that. Glad i helped!

Comment: Voted up using the green thingy :)

Answer (score 2):

you should call the glRotatef functions before you translate the camera, otherwise it will be rotated about the origin and not its position

Comment: Well, for some reason that's not rlly the problem, when i link the camera to the Event Keyboard Handler, it works fine (The only problem is I can't press multiple keys and hold them.)

But when I make it use 'SDL_GetKeyboardState' it does nothing.

Ill changed that btw, thx :D